# MathJax going wrong on Chrome

Tags: bug

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83431/a-problem-on-mathcalz-transforms-and-signal-stability) has the following raw title:

`A problem on $\mathcal{Z}-$transforms and signal stability`

but it renders like this on Chrome:

[image: Chrome rendering of title.]

and like this on Safari:

[image: Safari rendering of title.]

and like this on FireFox:

[image: FireFox rendering of title.]

So it seems to be a Chrome-specific problem, but I was wondering if SE can do anything about it?

Comment: It renders ok on my chrome ...